# Getting Error in starting docker machine in mac mojave

Tags: docker, virtualbox, docker-machine

When I start Docker Quickstart Terminal in MAC OS MOJAVE i'm getting following error

```
Starting "default"...
Unable to start the VM: /usr/local/bin/VBoxManage startvm default --type headless failed:
VBoxManage: error: The virtual machine 'default' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1 (0x1)
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component MachineWrap, interface IMachine

Details: 73:04:43.028351 ERROR [COM]: aRC=E_ACCESSDENIED (0x80070005) aIID={872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed} aComponent={ConsoleWrap} aText={The object is not ready}, preserve=false aResultDetail=0
Regenerate TLS machine certs?  Warning: this is irreversible. (y/n): Regenerating TLS certificates
Waiting for SSH to be available...
```

Any idea what's going on with the docker's default machine.

Answer (score 1):

I reinstalled Virtual Box that solved my issue.